# Material UI Textfield Can't Change Font Size for Multiline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to change the font size of a Material UI multiline TextField.  To do this, I am setting the `style` `InputProp` like so:

```
inputProps={{style: {fontSize: "14px"}}}
```

The problem is that the default input props styles are then overwritten, preventing the textfield's height from dynamically changing to accommodate multiple lines.

How do I properly change the font size of a multiline Material UI textfield?

Note: I'm using inline styles, not class names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to use `InputProps` (uppercase "I") instead of `inputProps`. The lowercase `inputProps` are passed to the final `textarea` element, but for the styling to work properly, the [`InputBase`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js) component that wraps the `textarea` in a `div` needs to have the correct font size.

Here's a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField multiline InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: 40 } }} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Multiline TextField]

Comment: I didn't know the difference between InputProps and inputProps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to change the font size of the Autocomplete input (which uses the Text Field component), then the selected answer will do it, but also break the dropdown menu because it overrides the entire `InputProps` object. You'll need to add your style updates on top of the old object:

```
renderInput={(params) => <TextField
  {...params}
  label="My Label"
  InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, style: { fontSize: 30 } }}
/>}
```